# Excluir 1 item do array

Tags: javascript, react, localstorage

Estou criando um TODO, armazenar uma lista. Quero excluir 1 item da lista tabem, quando clico em excluir ele excluir todo o array, zerando tudo. como faço para exlcuir somente item que clico em deletar.

```
const [nome, setNome] = useState("");



    let form = new Array();

    if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty("tarefas")) {
        form = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tarefas"))

    }
    const salvar = (tarefa) => {
        form.push({ item: tarefa })
        localStorage.setItem("tarefas", JSON.stringify(form));
    };

    const deletar = (tarefa) => {
        form.splice({ item: tarefa })
        localStorage.setItem("tarefas", JSON.stringify(form));
    };


    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <h1>Tarefa</h1>
                <form id="tarefa">
                    <input typeof="text" value={nome} onChange={(e) => setNome(e.target.value)}></input>
                    <button onClick={() => salvar(nome)}>Salvar</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <ul> {form.map(x =>
                <li>  {x.item} 
                   <button onClick={() => deletar(nome)}>Deletar</button>
                </li>)}
                
            </ul>
        </>
    );
```

Answer (score -1):

Dado a sua estrutura, acredito que existam duas possíveis soluções que você poderia implementar no seu código e vou explicá-las.

#### Solução 1: Método splice

Existe um método no JS para Arrays chamado `.splice()`, basicamente ele permite que você remova itens baseado nos indices e a quantidade de elementos para serem removidos do Array. No seu caso, você poderia usar esse mesmo método para remover o seu elemento do array fazendo da seguinte forma:

```js
const deletar = (tarefa) => {
        const tarefas = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tarefas"));
        const indiceTarefa = tarefas.findIndex((tarefaAtual) => {
          return tarefaAtual.item === tarefa;
        });
      
        // Aqui estou passando para o splice qual indice ele vai remover e quantos elementos vai remover, no caso será apenas 1
        tarefas.splice(indiceTarefa, 1);
        localStorage.setItem("tarefas", JSON.stringify(tarefas));
};
```

Assim o array te elementos irá eliminar a tarefa e armazenar no localStorage como devido.

#### Solução 2: Método filter

Existe também um método no JS para tratativa de arrays chamado `.filter()`, ele consiste em retornar um array baseado em um critério condicional que deve ser satisfeito por cada um dos seus elementos. No seu caso, a implementação poderia ser aplicada dessa forma:

```js
const deletar = (tarefa) => {
  const tarefas = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tarefas"));
  // Aqui estou dizendo que o array retornará todos os elementos do array que não tem item com o valor da tarefa especificada no atributo item
  const tarefasFiltradas = tarefas.filter((tarefaAtual) => {
    return tarefaAtual.item !== tarefa;
  });

  localStorage.setItem("tarefas", JSON.stringify(tarefas));
};
```

Aqui estão também os links de documentação de cada método, caso queira se aprofundar no funcionamento:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter